# An If-This-Than-That like service fire an HTTP requres triggered by Github Gists

Tags: github, if-this-then-that, zapier

I'm trying to fire a webhook(HTTP request) from [Zapier](http://zapier.com)(An If This Then That like service) when a new Github gist is posted, ie have a new gist as the trigger.

Zapier has GitHub integration, and supports webhooks, but sadly does not support gists.

I know there is a work around - create an RSS feed for the gists and use that as a trigger, but I'd prefer not having to do that.

Is there a way I can do this with Zapier, or if not, are there any other web-services/apps that have a similar functionality?

Comment: We we don't offer that now but we can look at it as Github offers webhooks for gists.
We would use the [CloudWork](https://cloudwork.com/) platform to build this integration. Could you please send more detailed requirements at info (at) cloudwork (.) com ? Thanks
Christophe
CloudWork

Comment: Please be careful about posting answers like this. They could be easily mistaken for spam or self promotion.

Comment: The edit was made in order to have this question be re-opened in your favour as the initial version was off topic

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise The edit has completely changed my question. I am not asking how to generate an rss feed for my gists. What in my question make you guys thinks I want to generate an rss feed, I cannot fathom, as I make it clear that I **know** I **can** generate an rss feed and get Zapier to do what I want, but I'd like a service that does it without needing a feed. Let me make it clear - I **do not** want create an rss feed for my gists. What I **want** is for a url to be called when I post a new gist. This is no different than ifttt tweeting everytime a new file a added on dropbox

Comment: And please explain to me how is my original question, or the previous edit of it, offtopic. Is it about webapps? Yes. Zapier is a webapp, it is like ifttt, and both have a tag for themselves on this SE, so questions related to either are not off topic. And yes, I am asking for an app recommendation, but I do show some prior research, albeit only the most relevant of the options I checked.

Comment: I'm rolling back, if you want to close, then go ahead. I'd rather have a closed question that asks what I wanted to ask, than an open one that is completely different from what I had intended to ask - That would be of no help to the community, and to future visitors to this question.

Comment: App recommendations are off topic but if you feel you can't make the edit to have it not be a shopping request that would help others instead of just yourself, then that is your choice to make.

Comment: From the [FAQ's](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-web-application-related-questions) --> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:** _App recommendations [**unless prior research is shown**](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1003/40)_ Now what would you consider prior research? Would it please you if I mentioned a bunch of other webapps I tried that didn't solve the problem? I don't see how that helps anyone, but if required I'll search google again for the useless information. All that'll do is create a list of ifttt like services.

Comment: A user tried to help your question become on-topic, which made it helpful, seeing that Zapier was able to integrate what was needed. Closed questions are eventually deleted, closure is a transitional period not permanence.

Comment: To rephrase the FAQ point, **we do not accept app recommendations**. What we do is recommend when the solution to the current app is not possible and via research all options that user did were exhausted. This is the compromise that Web Apps makes on the Stack Exchange (SE) no recommendations culture. We are actually more lenient than the overall action across the SE network.

Comment: FFS! How is it helping if the edit changes what's being asked? I don't mind an edit, specially if it improves my post, but if you change what I'm asking, then what's the use?

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Will edit the question to fix it. The FAQ needs to be clearer on this.

Comment: @phwd edited. Hope this fixes the issue. If not, then to hell with it.

Comment: I've re-opened the question, in the future refrain from "FFS" and "to hell with it", everyone here is trying to help. We will try to clean up that section of the FAQ soon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zapier co-founder here, for anyone else curious about how you might do this yourself, Github has really killer API docs which show [how to use their API to read/create your gists](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/). Its kind of annoying as you'll have to "poll" for new entries and compare them across time, but it isn't infeasible. Using a standar RSS reader like Google reader is a simple solution as you eluded to.

Further, this is a **great** suggestion, in fact I spent the last 30 minutes adding support for this. Its live now. If you have a Zapier account already, you'll need to add your Github account to us again to catch the new `gist` scope.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5spy.png]

For convenience's sake I've even spun up a quick template that [sends a POST whenever a new Gist is detected](https://zapier.com/z/8R/zapbook/github/webhook/5730/new-gists-sends-post-request/).

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks for the quick response, and solution